# Android - Display a progress bar if AsyncTask takes too long

Tags: android, timer, android-asynctask

Possible similarity : [Check if AsyncTask is taking too long](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3837445/check-if-asynctask-is-taking-too-long)

Hello everyone, I'm currently building an Android app to help my Mother managing her bills. To do so I fetch some data from my database using AsyncTask. Data isn't huge and doesn't need a progress bar assuming there is a good network connection, and I don't want to put one on good network condition, since it's so fast that the progress bar is shown then disapear right away which looks like a glitch.

However, considering network isn't always good, fetching the data could take more time and the user wouldn't know if his input was taken into consideration since it's a background thread and there is no UI information about the progress.

This is why I'd like to show a progress bar only if the AsyncTask is taking too long, though I've no idea nor the knowledge to implement such feature.

Bellow the AsyncTask :

```
@Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... values)
    {
        // connexion avec le serveur
        HttpURLConnection connexion = null;
        URL url = null;
        try {
            // ouvrir la connexion HTTP
            url = new URL(BASE_URL + scriptPath);
            connexion = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            // configurer la connexion en mode GET
            connexion.setReadTimeout(10000);
            connexion.setConnectTimeout(15000);
            connexion.setRequestMethod("GET");
            connexion.setDoInput(true);

            // récupérer la réponse du serveur
            InputStream reponse = connexion.getInputStream();

            // récupérer les données et en faire une chaîne
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(reponse, "utf-8"));
            String jsondata = "";
            String fromReader = "";


            while ((fromReader = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                // Add line to jsonString
                jsondata += (fromReader + "\n");
            }

            pd.dismiss(); //ProgressDialog started from the main thread

            return jsondata;

        } catch (Exception e) {

                Log.e("ERROR", e.toString());

            return null;

        } finally {
            // déconnexion obligatoire pour ne pas bloquer le serveur
            if (connexion != null) connexion.disconnect();
        }
    }
```

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: You could use the onProgressUpdate() method of the AsyncTask to check if progress is good (whatever your expected download rate criteria). If progress is not good then you can launch the progress bar. Alternatively you could start a timer for a certain time when you launch the AsyncTask and when the timer fires if you don't see good progress then you could launch the progress bar from there.

Comment: The problem is, there is no criteria to define how the task perform, there could be 100 rows returned in one case, and 2 in another case. Using a timer could be a good idea, I could run a timer in a background thread then add a boolean to OnPostExecute, if after a certain time boolean isn't true then start a progress bar.

Comment: If you don't know upfront how many entries to expect then of course it is tricky since you don't know how much further you need to go. In that case you probably will be unable to show any meaningful information in the progress bar anyway - what would X% done really mean? If there is some way to know number of entries upfront that would help. Also, even if at some point you somehow determined that progress is slow but this happens to be a point where you are almost done, displaying the progress bar would again look like a glitch.

Comment: Indeed that's tricky, I should probably stick with the idea of putting a progress dialog even on high speed network. Thanks for your input anyway. Have a nice day